# Scoring texts based on dictionaries other than positive / negative in Quanteda?

Tags: r, nlp, sentiment-analysis, quanteda

I would like to be able to give the texts in a very large corpus a score based on the number of words they contain from either 'Dictionary 1' (positive score), or 'Dictionary 2' (negative score). Can anybody help me to figure out how to do this?

I have read up on the use of Quanteda for sentiment analysis https://tutorials.quanteda.io/advanced-operations/targeted-dictionary-analysis/ and it seems like that is essentially just scoring texts based on whether they contain words from lists of 'positive' and 'negative' words.

I would like to use Quanteda for this, as I am familiar with the package.

How can I make modified dictionary which doesn't contain two lists of positive and negative words, but two list of other kinds of words e.g. 'right wing' and 'left wing' for example? I already know the words I wish to include in each list.

Comment: Are you asking, how do you create a custom dictionary of words you want to have in a "right-wing" category and a "left-wing" category? See `?dictionary`. If I misunderstood the question though, please be more specific and provide some form of example and expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and sorry that I didn't write a more specific question - I was more just trying to think through how to do the whole thing. I now think I've got something to work on: I will use to `?dictionary` to work out how to make my own dictionary - then follow the [link]https://tutorials.quanteda.io/advanced-operations/targeted-dictionary-analysis/ but directing to dictionary = mycustomdictionary instead of 'data_dictionary_LSD2015'